# Updating a SQL database with a .gz file

Tags: sql

There is public database that I can download with rsync (mydb.sql.gz). It is a fairly large compressed file, about 130MB. When uncompressed, the database is about 1.3GiB. New data is added to it daily. What is the most efficient way to update my local copy with the remote database's new data?

Comment: Is the data being sent new records only or the entire database?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: @Rob it's the entire DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can uncompress it on the fly while importing. Assuming MySQL, this command should work:

```
gunzip -c mydb.sql.gz | mysql mydb -h host -u user -p
```

Note: `-c` means write output to stdout.

BTW: Using rsync to download a compressed file may not gain you much. Even small changes in the uncompressed data may result in large changes in the compressed equivalent. You might be better off simply using `wget` or `curl` to download the whole file daily.

Comment: Okay, so maybe I don't understand a few basic things here. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

First, I thought that compressing a file would make rsync re-download the entire file anyway, since how would it know what changed? The data provider only has a rsync sample up in their instructions, so I assumed this was the only way to grab the file anyway.

Second, what would happen if I deleted or archived a bunch of old rows in the DB that I don't actually need and then did this? Would they get added back in along with the new rows?

Comment: Yes, changes in the uncompressed file causes large change in the compressed file, which would cause rsync to re-download practically the whole file again, thereby negating any benefit you would get from using rsync over curl. In fact, rsync would probably waste time difing the files. Regarding your second question: my assumption was that the daily image was the complete database and that you would be wiping out whatever you had locally and creating a new db based on the daily gz file. So whatever is in the daily dump that you don't want comes back each day.